# use of **kwargs for backward compatibility

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used to have a function that took some keyword parameters :  `def foo(a=None, b=None)`

In a new version of my code, I don't need one of the keywords (`b`) anymore and wants to remove it.

Should I add `**kwargs` in my function like so `def foo(a=None, **kwargs)` for backward compatibility or is it not needed?

**What is the best practice in this situation?**

I don't want to break my user's code if they upgrade to the new version of my package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the best practice in this situation?

In one release, add a deprecation warning *without changing the function signature*.

```
import warnings

def foo(a=None, b=None):
    if b is not None:
        warnings.warn("use of b is deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
    ...
```

You're still obliged to handle `b` for now, so don't just ignore it -  a deprecation warning indicates that "it will be going away", not that "it's already gone away"!

Mention that this keyword is deprecated in your release notes, and in the docs, saying that it will be removed in the next version. Then in the next release - in a major release, *maybe* a minor release, but not bugfix micro release - you can just remove it.

```
def foo(a=None):
    ...
```

Mention that this argument has been removed in your release notes, and remove it from the docs completely.

Related reading: [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can define `def foo(a=None, **kwargs)` which:

- logs a deprecated info
- calls a `def foo(a=None)` which is the actual one processing what you want